# AMcharts Map in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, maps, amcharts

I am currently working on AM Charts Maps. I want to implement below link in angularjs. How do I convert into angular js? Should i have to implement directive?

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/chxownuh/1/)

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following files for the component.

**map.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent {
    private id = "mapdiv";

    private options;

    makeChartConfig() {

        return {
            "type": "map",
            "theme": "light",

            "colorSteps": 10,

            "dataProvider": {
                "map": "indiaLow",
                "areas": [{
                    "id": "IN-AN",
                    "value": 4447100
                }, {
                    "id": "IN-AP",
                    "value": 626932
                }, {
                    "id": "IN-KA",
                    "value": 5130632
                }]
            },

            "areasSettings": {
                "autoZoom": true
            },

            "valueLegend": {
                "right": 10,
                "minValue": "little",
                "maxValue": "a lot!"
            }

        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.options = this.makeChartConfig();
    }
}
```

**map.component.html**

```
<amCharts [id]="id" [options]="options" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></amCharts>
```